# Will my EC2 T3 webserver have same public IP Address when an extra instance is created under Auto Scaling?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I currently use a single EC2 T3 instance for our webserver. I'm thinking of creating a Launch Template for EC2 and create Auto Scaling Group with Desired=Min=1 instance & max=3 T3 instances. It is an Ubuntu webserver with Wordpress website.

Please may I know what actually happens when it scales from 1 to 3 instances? Like, will all 3 instances have the same public ip address as the initial 1st instance running to cope with a heavy spike in web traffic? Would be really grateful for any tips/guidance on this matter. Thanks very much!

Comment: Each Amazon EC2 instance in a VPC will have a different **private IP address**. If you wish to send traffic to EC2 instances, then you will either need each instance to have a different **public IP address** or you will send traffic to a Load Balancer that then distributes the traffic amongst multiple EC2 instances.

Comment: If you only intend having **one** instance in an Auto Scaling group, you could reassign an **Elastic IP address**. See: [Amazon Route 53: How to automatically update IP addresses without using Elastic IPs - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/amazon-route-53-how-to-automatically-update-ip-addresses-without-using-elastic-ips-h7o)

Answer (score 1):

No, instances within an ASG do not share IP addresses.  You would typically [Use Elastic Load Balancing to distribute traffic across the instances in your Auto Scaling group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/autoscaling-load-balancer.html):

> To use Elastic Load Balancing with your Auto Scaling group, attach the load balancer to your Auto Scaling group. This registers the group with the load balancer, which acts as a single point of contact for all incoming web traffic to your Auto Scaling group.